# Windows 7 - Windows Update won't update

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

I'm trying to update my Windows 7 Professional 32-bit edition and when I try to tell Windows Update to scan for updates it failed with the error code **0x80096001**.

I checked out WindowsUpdate.log and it appears this is the problem:

`Validating signature for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\WuRedir\9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77\muv4wuredir.cab:
WARNING: Error: 0x80096001 when verifying trust for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\WuRedir\9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77\muv4wuredir.cab
WARNING: Digital Signatures on file C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\WuRedir\9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77\muv4wuredir.cab are not trusted: Error 0x80096001`

How can I go about fixing this? It looks like it's just this one (corrupted?) file that's causing the problem.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Upon inspecting the file mentioned in the error message it appears that the file does not exist! What does this mean and how do I get it back?

UPDATE 2: Ok it appears that the file in question appears only for a split second when Windows Updating is trying to search (but fails) to find updates. So I guess the problem doesn't have to do with the file specifically then.

Comment: It could be a corrupted user profile, create a new user account and migrate to it...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/Fix-a-corrupted-user-profile

Comment: I tried Windows Update with a newly created account and it failed with the same error code.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Check your system time to be sure it is correct.

Copy the text below into a text file, then save it as a .bat file and execute it, this will reset Windows Update. Be sure the text below is in a text file as separate lines as shown.

When done run a manual Windows Update, it may take some time to list the updates because it has to rebuild the Softwaredistribution files.

> net stop wuauserv
>
> rmdir %windir%\softwaredistribution /s /q
>
> rmdir %windir%\system32\softwaredistribution /s /q
>
> regsvr32 /s wuaueng.dll
>
> regsvr32 /s wuaueng1.dll
>
> regsvr32 /s atl.dll
>
> regsvr32 /s wups.dll
>
> regsvr32 /s wups2.dll
>
> regsvr32 /s wuweb.dll
>
> regsvr32 /s wucltui.dll
>
> net start wuauserv

.

EDIT: This is the short version of the reset procedure, but should fix your Softwaredistribution folder corruption, the Full reset Fixit and manual fix it myself instructions [can be found here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058).

EDIT:If for some reason deleting the Softwaredistribution folder fails, boot from a linux cd and delete it from there.

.

Comment: There is a lot more to resetting the Windows Update components. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058. There is a Fix-It there also.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, Mine is the short version which will fix the OP's softwaredistruibution folder corruption.

Comment: I've already tried this fix before, also while running the .bat it said this: `rmdir C:\Windows\system32\softwaredistribution /s /q
The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Manually navigate to that folder in explorer, is it there? You may have to unhide system and hidden folders to see it. Also check my edit at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: It's not there because I already tried deleting it before.

Comment: I suspect maleware or a rootkit.

Answer (score 1):

I created & ran the `.bat` file per the blog entry above. I copied the `softwareDistribution` folder (Windows folder) from a PC where updates were working to the Windows folder on the problematic PC.

This resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to repair system files..

Click the Start Orb & type cmd.exe into the search menu.

Right click it & run as Administrator.

Type the following command: `sfc /scannow` & hit enter.

Wait for the process to finish, when it's done. Reboot the system.

then try again..
if it does not work then use `microsoft fixit tool`.

there may be some other issue so follow these links for more information.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/windows-update-problem-80096001-error-code/e7110943-588d-4b07-84c7-ce7416fb999b?tab=MoreHelp

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/el-GR/genuinewindows7/thread/20d5ef9d-acf8-4efb-b748-e451048629a6

if all fail then go to Microsoft online update website.. use this it works mostly for me when auto update give error in updating windows for me..

Comment: I have already tried `sfc /scannow` several times already, what happens is that at the end the window says that it found problems but couldn't fix them. However when I look at the CSP.log file there are no reports of any problems which is strange. Also already tried Microsoft Fix-It tool and it scanned and didn't find any problems. I have also already tried MicrosoftFixit50202.exe and MicrosoftFixit50528.exe and neither worked.

Comment: See this article, there are manual solutions besides the fixit....http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822798

Comment: Free Windows Update support from Microsoft..https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?LN=en-us&gprid=6527&x=18&y=11&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn

Comment: have you tried to install updates online from Microsoft website??

Comment: @Moab I've already done all of the fixes including the manual fixes, none helped. I have already started a support ticket with Microsoft but they didn't help and tried to pawn me off on to the MSE support folks for some reason.
_NiranjanKala:_ Whenever I try to install any sort of Windows updates I get the **0x80096001** error and it fails.

Comment: Check the date and time of your system clock, be sure it is correct

Comment: @Moab Yup date and time are both correct.